# Proper Indexing/Optimization of a MySQL GROUP BY and JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I've done a lot of reading and Googling on this and I cannot find any satisfactory answer so I'd appreciate any help.  Most answers I find come close to my situation but do not address it (and attempting to follow the solutions has not done me any good).

**See Edit #2 below for the best example**

---

[This was the original question but is not a great representation of what I'm asking.]

Say I have 2 tables, each with 4 columns:

- key (int, auto increment)
- c1 (a date)
- c2 (a varchar of length 3)
- c3 (also a varchar of length 3)

And I want to perform the following query:

```
SELECT t.c1, t.c2, COUNT(*)
FROM test1 t
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.key = t.key
GROUP BY t.c1, t.c2
```

Both `key` fields are indexed as primary keys.  I want to get the number of rows returned in each grouping of c1, c2.

When I explain this query I get "using temporary; using filesort". The actual table I'm performing this query on is over 500,000 rows, so that means it's a time consuming query.

So my question is (assuming I'm not doing anything wrong in the query): is there a way to index this table to eliminate the temporary/filesort usage?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit**

Here is the table definition (in this example both tables are identical - in reality they're not but I'm not sure it makes a difference at this point):

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
 `key` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `c1` date NOT NULL,
 `c2` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `c3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`key`),
 UNIQUE KEY `c1` (`c1`,`c2`),
 UNIQUE KEY `c2_2` (`c2`,`c1`),
 KEY `c2` (`c2`,`c3`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Full EXPLAIN statement:

```
id   select_type  table  type    possible_keys  key      key_len  ref             rows   Extra
1    SIMPLE       t      ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL            2      Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE       t2     eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        tracking.t.key  1      Using index
```

This is just for my sample tables.  In my real tables the rows for t says 500,000+ (every row in the table, though that could be related to something else).

---

**Edit #2**

Here is a more concrete example to better explain my situation.

Let's say I have data on Little League baseball games.  I have two tables.  One holds data on the games:

```
CREATE TABLE `ex_games` (
 `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `home_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`game_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The other holds data on the at bats in each game:

```
CREATE TABLE `ex_atbats` (
 `ab_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `game` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `team` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `player` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `result` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`hit_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So I have two questions.  Let's start with the simple version: I want to return a list of games with a count of how many at bats are in each game.  So I think I would do something like this:

```
SELECT date, home_team, COUNT(h.ab_id) FROM `ex_atbats` h
LEFT JOIN ex_games g ON g.game_id = h.game
GROUP BY g.game_id
```

This query uses filesort/temporary.  Is there a better way to structure this or to index the tables to get rid of that?

Then, the trickier part: say I now want to not only include a count of the number of at bats, but also include a count of the number of at bats that were preceded by an at bat with the same result by the same team.  I assume that would be something like:

```
SELECT g.date, g.home_team, COUNT(ab.ab_id), COUNT(ab2.ab_id) FROM `ex_atbats` ab
LEFT JOIN ex_games g ON g.game_id = ab.game
LEFT JOIN ex_atbats ab2 ON ab2.ab_id = ab.ab_id - 1 AND ab2.result = ab.result
GROUP BY g.game_id
```

Is that the correct way to structure that query?  This also uses filesort/temporary.

So what is the optimal way to go about accomplishing these tasks?

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried an index in table `test1`, on `(c1,c2)` ?

Comment: Yeah, no luck - still gives me the same temporary/filesort.

Comment: The current edit will just return a list of unqualified numbers. Perhaps you wnat `SELECT t.c1, t.c2, count(*)` instead?

Comment: What does `explain` say in `key` and `key_len` colums? Show us complete table definitions.

Comment: Is it MyISAM or InnoDB ?

Comment: Do you only want results from table `test1` - and the aggregate `COUNT(*)` ?

Comment: OK, table definitions and EXPLAIN now in the original post.

Comment: In my actual implementation I do take 1 field from test2, but most fields selected are from test 1.

Answer (score 2):

Phrases `Using temporary/filesort` usually are not related to the indexes used in the `JOIN` operation. There is numerous examples where you can have all indexes set (they show up in `key` and `key_len` columns in `EXPLAIN`) but you still get `Using temporary` and `Using filesort`.

Check out what the manual says about `Using temporary` and `Using filesort`:

- [How MySQL Uses Internal Temporary Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)
- [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Having a combined index for all columns used in `GROUP BY` clause may help to get rid of `Using filesort` in certain circumstances. If you also issue `ORDER BY` you may need to add more complex indexes.

If you have a huge dataset consider partitioning it using some criteria like date or timestamp by means of [actual partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) or a simple `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the tables' definitions do matter. It's one thing to join using two primary keys, another to join using a primary key from one side and a non-unique key in the other, etc. It also matters what type of engine the tables use as InnoDB treats Primary Keys differently than MyISAM engine.

---

What I notice though is that on table `test1`, the `(c1,c2)` combination is Unique and the fields are not nullable. This allows your query to be rewritten as:

```
SELECT t.c1, t.c2, COUNT(*)
FROM test1 t
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.key = t.key
GROUP BY t.key
```

It will give the same results while using the same field for the `JOIN` and the `GROUP BY`. Note that MySQL allows you to use in the `SELECT` list fields that are not in the `GROUP BY` list, without having aggregate functions on them. This is not allowed in most other systems and is seen as a bug by some. In this situation though it is a very nice feature. Every row can be either identified by `(key)` or `(c1,c2)`, so it shouldn't matter which of the two is used for the grouping.

---

Another thing to note is that when you use `LEFT JOIN`, it's common to use the joining column from the right side for the counting: `COUNT(t2.key)` and not `COUNT(*)`. Your original query will give `1` in that column for records in `test1` that do not mmatch any record in `test2` because it counts rows while you probably want to count the related records in `test2` - and show `0` in those cases.

So, try this query and post the EXPLAIN:

```
SELECT t.c1, t.c2, COUNT(t2.key)
FROM test1 t
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.key = t.key
GROUP BY t.key
```

Comment: Thanks, ypercube, this is helpful.  Unfortunately I bungled the abstraction of my actual problem, and my actual implementation does not contain this unique feature.

So I added in Edit #2 above to better clarify my situation.  That's the question I should have originally asked.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes help with the join, but you still need to do a full sort in order to do the group by. Essentially, it still has to process every record in the set.

Adding a where clause and limiting the set would run faster, of course. It just won't get you the results you want.

There may be other options than doing a group by on the entire table. I notice you're doing a SELECT * - What are you trying to get out of the query?

SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2
   FROM test t
   LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.key = t.key

*may* run faster, for instance. (I realize this was just a sample query, but understand that it's hard to optimize when you don't know what the end goal is!)

*EDIT* - In doing some reading (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html), I learned that, under the correct circumstances, indexes can help significantly with the group by.

What I'm seeing is that it needs to be a sorted index (like BTREE), not a HASH. Perhaps:

```
CREATE INDEX c1c2 IN t (c1, c2) USING BTREE;
```

might help.

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  The actual usage is far more complicated so I was trying to boil it down to what I believe is the main issue.  I don't think DISTINCT will work, unfortunately, since what I want to do is (among other things) count the number of rows returned for each combination of c1 and c2.  I will edit the original post to make that a little more clear.

Comment: To your edit: I've read the same thing, and I have a BTREE index of (c1,c2) on both tables.  Doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For innodb it will work, as the index caries your primary key by default. For myisam you have to have the key as the last column of your index be "key". That will give the optimizers all keys in the same order and he can skip the sort. You cannot do any range queryies on the index prefix theN, puts you right back into filesort. currently struggling with a similiar problem